# How up to date is the Polymer Browser Compatibility page?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, polymer

http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/compatibility.html

I need to know how up-to-date this page is and I'm also specifically wondering whether to adopt Polymer/Platform into production apps with support for Android Browser 4.0+ and IE9 support as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Production means things to different people. [chromestatus.com](http://www.chromestatus.com), [polymer-project.org](http://polymer-project.org), and [others](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/wiki/Who's-using-Polymer%3F) are already using Polymer in production, but it really depends on your pain tolerance. Churn will dramatically go down when Chrome and other browsers ship the native APIs. We're still iterating on Polymer itself (it's alpha :)).

I also just updated the browsers compat chart. A couple of notes:

- Android Browser is not supported.
- IE9 is not supported. IE11 is our target browser. IE10 is sketchy because of the flaky implementation of Mutation Observers.

Comment: I'm planning to use it in Prod now. The time and money saved is worth losing the minority of older browsers for me.

Comment: As from the FAQ:
"Most things should work in IE9 today without too much work; feel free to file bugs on what doesn’t."

Every page with polymer now throws a javascript error (in platform.js) in IE9.

Comment: Does this still apply two years later?

Comment: Seems like the Polymer 1.0 docs report IE10+ compatibility, but the webcomponents polyfill page reports IE10 as flaky. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/resources/compatibility.html https://github.com/WebComponents/webcomponentsjs#browser-support

Answer (score -2):

Most things should work in IE9 today without too much work. (https://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html)

Polymer's poylfills are only "guaranteed" to work on Chrome for Android 4.4.3 and above. ([Does Polymer support lower android versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849944/does-polymer-support-lower-android-versions))

Comment: I think you didn't check who @ebidel is :)