# Does Polymer support lower android versions?

Tags: android, android-webview, polymer

Can any one please let me know whether Polymer supports Android lower versions i.e. from 2.2

I have read that Polymer supports from Android version 4.4.3.

I have a website which is designed using Polymer and I want to use this URL in Android Webview.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polymer's poylfills are only "guaranteed" to work on Chrome for Android 4.4.3 and above. This means no support for the older webview. To gain support in the legacy webview, many have been successful with [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org).

Comment: crosswalk is a good solution. but my hello world app got 69mb size :(