# Apache cordova, ionic & polymer paper elements : android version

Tags: android, cordova, polymer, ionic-framework

I'm actually trying to develop a simple application using Apache Cordova, Ionic and polymer paper elements.

Actually, the app works great on device with version > 4.3 (excluding Jelly Bean so)
I'm now looking for something that allows me to use this app with version > 2.2 (Froyo)

I have read the crosswalk documentation, but it seems that it allows only to use on version > 4.0 and it's not what I'm looking for.

So : how can I make my Cordova / Polymer / Ionic application working on Android > 2.2 (permitting me to use every Cordova briges) ?

Thanks for advance

Comment: You need to set it in the AndroidManifest.xml within your Android project

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="18"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18"
        />

Change the minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion and maxSdkVersion according to your requirements.

Comment: Not working. I think it's a bit harder :-/

Comment: Ionic does not support Android that far back. Also Polymer doesn't run that far back either. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849944/does-polymer-support-lower-android-versions

Comment: Any reason for this? Seems like a world of pain to try and use a cutting edge platforms to support very old versions of android.

Comment: Does it exist another "graphical framework" to work with and to make app > 2.2 version ?

Answer (score 0):

Crosswalk is the answer.

https://crosswalk-project.org/

I will also recommend to check this repos

MobileChromeApps
https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps

ChromeDevEditor
https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor

You can easily create an iOS, Android and ChromeApp with just one code base. Is in beta and still needs more development, but i find it really promising.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In my post, I ve mentionned crosswalk. But it doesnt work as expected

Comment: Have you tried to run it using the ChromeDevEditor? Other alternative is Cocoonjs http://support.ludei.com/hc/en-us/articles/202568973-First-steps-with-CocoonJS-CLI. Please let us know if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most of time, the Ionic Framework Layout will cause some trouble when you try to use other Front Framework, but you can use Cordova-Angular-Polymer (The Ionic Base without they're Layout).

If you want, I have a seed that should help:
https://github.com/mario-aleo/cordova-angular-polymer-seed